# How to specify packages source?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, pypi

My package depends of PyMySQL.
Problem:
Then I upload package to test.pypi.org and try to install it `pip install -U -i https://testpypi.python.org/pypi scrapy-mysql-pipeline` I got a exception in my code because PyMySQL version on test.pypi.org is 0.6.3-rc1 instead of current 0.7.11
My `setup.py`:

```
import setuptools
import os

if "PY_DEV" in os.environ:
    import pypandoc
    with open('README.rst', 'w') as f:
        f.write(pypandoc.convert('README.md', 'rst'))
else:
    os.environ.update(SKIP_WRITE_GIT_CHANGELOG='1')
os.environ.update(SKIP_GENERATE_AUTHORS='1')
setuptools.setup(
    setup_requires=['pbr', ],
    pbr=True
)
```

My `setup.cfg`:

```
[metadata]
name = scrapy-mysql-pipeline
author = Iaroslav Russkykh
author-email = iarruss@ya.ru
summary = Asynchronous mysql Scrapy item pipeline
license = MIT
description-file = README.rst
home-page = https://github.com/IaroslavR/scrapy-mysql-pipeline
requires-python = >=2.7
classifier =
    Development Status :: 4 - Beta
    Framework :: Scrapy
    Intended Audience :: Developers
    License :: OSI Approved :: Apache Software License
    Operating System :: OS Independent
    Programming Language :: Python
    Topic :: Internet :: WWW/HTTP

[files]
packages =
    scrapy_mysql_pipeline

[wheel]
universal = 1
```

This `requirements.txt` cause error in pip: `No matching distribution found for pymysql>=0.7.11 (from scrapy-mysql-pipeline)`

```
scrapy>=1.4.0
pymysql>=0.7.11
```

How do I specify to use packages from pypi.org?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `--extra-index-url`:

```
pip install -U --index-url=https://testpypi.python.org/pypi --extra-index-url=https://pypi.python.org/pypi scrapy-mysql-pipeline
```

Comment: Not working for me: `Marker evaluation failed, see the following error.  For more information see: http://docs.openstack.org/developer/pbr/compatibility.html#evaluate-marker
    -------extremely long traceback skipped ----------
    SyntaxError: Invalid marker: '(--index-url=https://pypi.python.org/simple/)', parse error at '--index-'
    error in setup command: Error parsing /home/elruso/projects/python-packages/scrapy-mysql-pipeline/setup.cfg: SyntaxError: Invalid marker: '(--index-url=https://pypi.python.org/simple/)', parse error at '--index-'`